# CSS Custom Font render flaw on ios

Tags: ios, css, fonts

I made a custom font with an arrow "A", exported it to .eot .svg and .ttf font formats and put it on my website with the following css:

```
@font-face{
    font-family: 'Nautix-Light';
    src: url('Nautix-Light.eot');
    src: url('Nautix-Light.eot?iefix') format('eot'),
    url('Nautix-Light.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('Nautix-Light.svg#webfont') format('svg');
}
```

It works well on Android Devices and on Mac with Firefox and Safari, but on the iPhone 6 it has a rendering flaw:

[image]

The peaks should be sharp, but they are doubled on the iPhone 6, as seen on the Screenshot.

Any Ideas what might cause this problem - or what i could try to solve it?

Comment: Not sure if that's your case, but "many mobile devices (mobile safari included) style heading tags (h1-h6) with something like font-weight: bold. If the font you are using doesn’t include a bold weight, then the browser will create a faux bold and offset that" ([source](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/weird-mobile-safari-font-face-problem-font-doubled-and-offset-to-the-left/))

Comment: Yes, thats it. Thank you :) Could you write that as an answer, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated [on CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/weird-mobile-safari-font-face-problem-font-doubled-and-offset-to-the-left/), many mobile devices (mobile safari included) have default css for heading tags (h1-h6) with bolder typeface, something like `font-weight: bold`.

If the font you are using doesn’t include a bold weight, then the browser will create a faux bold and offset that. That's why the letter seems doubled.

If you're not willing to draw your font for different typefaces, either add a bold typeface with the same source font, or always force a `normal` font weight wherever your font is used.